# "Without a rest stop" vs. "Without stopping a rest" vs. "Without (pronoun) stop for a rest"

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

> 1. At the time it was felt that engines and passengers could not survive the journey ***without a rest stop***.
> 2. At the time it was felt that engines and passengers could not survive the journey ***without stopping a rest***.
> 3. At the time it was felt that engines and passengers could not survive the journey ***without they stop for a rest***.

1 is a random sentence I found on Internet, presumably on an British site; 2 and 3 are varied forms of 1.

Supposing 1 is good English, are 2 and 3 okay, too? If so, are there differences in meaning?

Comment: #2 has to be *without stopping **for** a rest,* and (I think) #3 is non-standard "dialectal" (I often use it myself, but I suspect not everyone approves! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I've heard #3 too, usually in Gangster movies set in NYC, and it's pronounced, "widdout dey stop for a rest."

Comment: @Jim: I'm sure most of several thousand instances of ["without I have to"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22without+I+have+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are for this usage (I doubt many of them are the reported speech of Noo York Eye-talian gangsters! :)

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is correct, though it refers to a "rest stop" (a place for resting) rather than just a rest. It could include additional activity such as eating or taking a nap.

The second sentence could be

> At the time it was felt that engines and passengers could not survive the journey without stopping **for** a rest.

As for the third sentence, it could be

> At the time it was felt that engines and passengers could not survive the journey **unless** they **stopped** for a rest.

But I don't see much real difference in meaning between them.

Comment: #1 needn't refer to a *place* - it can refer to an *action*, with *a stop* = *a break* = *a breather* = *a recess*.

Comment: "Rest stop" in this sense very often doesn't mean a real "rest" (to recover from being tired), but for the use of a "rest room", another euphemism for "comfort station".